# Bootstrap Tabs in HTML content variable in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

First I use `ui.routing`

I have template and there

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustHtml(page)"></div>
```

In controller I have

```
$scope.trustHtml = function(page) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(page);
}
```

But I want inside that `page` to show bootstrap markup tabs.

```
var page = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
  '<li class="active"><a href="#t1" data-toggle="tab">T1</a></li>' +
  '<li><a href="#t2" data-toggle="tab">T2</a></li>' +
'</ul>' +
'<div class="tab-content">' +
  '<div class="tab-pane active" id="t1">Tab 1</div>' +
  '<div class="tab-pane" id="t2">Tab 2</div>' +
'</div>';
```

But those tabs uses `href="#tab1"` for tab navigation. So when I click I simply change navigation to .

How can I use tabs inside HTML text variables?

This is JSFIddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Serhioromano/qkpFb/)
But this is working because it is without routing. This is only demonstrate how it works. But in real code when I click tabs it routs instead of tab switch.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved this issue if anyone is interested.

I changed

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustHtml(page)"></div>
```

to

```
<div ng-if="page" ng-include="load(page)"></div>
```

And I load it

```
$scope.page = 'MyPage.html';
$scope.load = function(page) {
    return '/structure/html_pages/' + page;
}
```

Because before I was loading it with `$http` and inserted as HTML content. Now everything is processed and I can use any angular stuff in it.